# PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"

Tags: linux, networking, centos, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a problem with CentOS 6.4 on Hyper-V. I can't install using *yum* or ping any DNS address. There is a announcement: `Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'` etc.  I've been trying to fix it according to this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BZHvVpXsg4 but still nothing. What should I do?
[image: yum]

[image: ifconfig]

[image: ping]

Comment: Is network set up on virtual machine? Try "ifconfig".

Comment: It's set up. Print-screen: http://i.imgur.com/2K8uOaY.png

Comment: Try "ping mirrorlist.centos.org" and then "traceroute mirrorlist.centos.org".

Comment: That's minimal version of CentOS. Can't find: traceroute. Print-screen: http://i.imgur.com/JCEKfPs.png

Comment: Definitely routing setup is wrong. I can't help more because I don't have experience with Hyper-V. In Virtual Box it's enough to set network as NAT Access.

Answer (score 13):

Check network ... I use vm-player and add custom-virtual-network ( vmnet bridget )

Type:

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
yum update
```

for me works ....

Comment: This also solved the problem I was having after installing Centos 6.5 under VMware ESXi 5.0 using the 'Web Server' configuration.

Comment: Not only did this enable yum, but it also established an inet addr (found via 'ifconfig') to which I could connect to remotely via ssh (via Git for Windows + ConEmu). Genius.

This answer was dead-on perfect and saved another four hours of looking for what seemed to be a needle in a haystack of threads and answers that were absolutely worthless.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this line into the `/etc/hosts`

```
64.235.47.134    mirrorlist.centos.org
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

After logining my compony account, the networking can connect the Internet. But my vitrual manchine cound not login.

I change the network mode, use the **"private network"**, then can connect the Internet.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: if you are in a **Python shell**, try to **start a new one.** I know the question is not about this, but it is the only top hit from google for this error. The original reason of the issue is still not clear as `curl` from command line downloaded the same URL with no problem, and I had no networking issue in any other application at the same time. I did `ip link set <ifname> down/up`, `nmcli con down/up wired` with no success. I added some of the domains to `/etc/hosts`, this once hasn't resolved the problem, but later at an other domain it worked. Here is a minimal example for easy testing:

```
import pycurl
import io

s = io.BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, s.write)
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db')
c.perform()
s.seek(0)
print('Downloaded %u bytes.' % len(s.getvalue()))
```